# Generating checkboxes for answers to quiz questions with a loop over a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, createelement

I'm working through the "Learn JavaScript" path on javascriptissexy.com, and have progressed to the point of working on the quiz. I've figured out pretty much everything I've done by looking either at books, or posts on here. I doubt the code is pretty but given that this is the first project I've EVER done, I'm pretty proud.

Anyways, I've used a constructor and a for loop to add the questions to one div, and the possible answers into another innerDiv. What I can't figure out is how to get the innerDiv answers to appear as checkboxes.

I changed this line:

```
var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

To:

```
var innerDiv = document.createElement('input');
```

But all that does is change it to a text input box, and any other change I've made has just broke the code. I'm getting frustrated, but don't want to quit, I love doing this and I really wanna learn it.

Can someone help me? I know I could've done this WAY easier with jQuery, but I'm trying to learn it the hard way first, then when I get it working this way, I'm going to go back and alter it to work better and more efficiently.

Here is a jsfiddle of the code working: http://jsfiddle.net/joshrlangley/prx9h8sm/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new input object, set the attributes of this object to make it a checkbox, then add it to the DOM:

```
    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    cb.setAttribute("value", q.Answer[j]);
    innerDiv.appendChild(cb);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/prx9h8sm/1/

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as answer if this solves your problem ;)